# How to order a python dictionary containing a list of values

Tags: python, dictionary, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm not sure I am approaching this in the right way.

**Scenario:**

I have two SQL tables that contain rent information. One table contains rent due, and the other contains rent received.

I'm trying to build a rent book which takes the data from both tables for a specific lease and generates a date ordered statement which will be displayed on a webpage.

I'm using Python, Flask and SQL Alchemy.

I am currently learning Python, so I'm not sure if my approach is the best.

I've created a dictionary which contains the keys 'Date', 'Payment type' and 'Payment Amount', and in each of these keys I store a list which contains the data from my SQL queries. The bit im struggling on is how to sort the dictionary so it sorts by the date key, keeping the values in the other keys aligned to their date.

```
lease_id = 5
dates_list = []
type_list = []
amounts_list = []

rentbook_dict = {}

payments_due = Expected_Rent_Model.query.filter(Expected_Rent_Model.lease_id == lease_id).all()
payments_received = Rent_And_Fee_Income_Model.query.filter(Rent_And_Fee_Income_Model.lease_id == lease_id).all()

for item in payments_due:

    dates_list.append(item.expected_rent_date)
    type_list.append('Rent Due')
    amounts_list.append(item.expected_rent_amount)

for item in payments_received:
    dates_list.append(item.payment_date)
    type_list.append(item.payment_type)
    amounts_list.append(item.payment_amount)

rentbook_dict.setdefault('Date',[]).append(dates_list)
rentbook_dict.setdefault('Type',[]).append(type_list)
rentbook_dict.setdefault('Amount',[]).append(amounts_list)
```

I was then going to use a for loop within the flask template to iterate through each value and display it in a table on the page.

Or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

Comment: A Python dictionary only has one key.  Each of those three statements changes what the current key is.  They are not cumulative.  Perhaps your best plan here is not to create a dictionary at all, but just create a list of lists (or tuples).  If you put the date first, you can sort the list and get everything in date order.  If you're not accessing the data by key, then there's no point in creating a key/data mapping.

Comment: I was just researching this in more detail and I think that's what I need to do. I can zip the 3 lists (dates_list, type_list, amounts_list) and then sort by the date I think?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.  You don't really need to zip them; you're already getting the rows as rows.  `payments_due` already has has rows.  You're splitting them in your loops.  So, Don't Do That.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

so I managed to get this working just using zipped list. Im sure there is a better way for me to accomplish this but im pleased I've got it working.

```
lease_id = 5
payments_due = Expected_Rent_Model.query.filter(Expected_Rent_Model.lease_id == lease_id).all()
payments_received = Rent_And_Fee_Income_Model.query.filter(Rent_And_Fee_Income_Model.lease_id == lease_id).all()

total_due = 0
for debit in payments_due:
    total_due = total_due + int(debit.expected_rent_amount)

total_received = 0
for income in payments_received:
    total_received = total_received + int(income.payment_amount)

balance = total_received - total_due

if balance < 0 :
    arrears = "This account is in arrears"
else:
    arrears = ""

dates_list = []
type_list = []
amounts_list = []

for item in payments_due:

    dates_list.append(item.expected_rent_date)
    type_list.append('Rent Due')
    amounts_list.append(item.expected_rent_amount)

for item in payments_received:
    dates_list.append(item.payment_date)
    type_list.append(item.payment_type)
    amounts_list.append(item.payment_amount)

payment_data = zip(dates_list, type_list, amounts_list)
sorted_payment_data = sorted(payment_data)
tuples = zip(*sorted_payment_data)
list1, list2, list3 = [ list(tuple) for tuple in  tuples]

return(render_template('rentbook.html', 
payment_data = zip(list1,list2,list3),
total_due = total_due,
total_received = total_received,
balance = balance))
```